# Django Rest Framework: MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It´s a requirement of the project to start from an existing database. In which there are tables with compound keys. When generating the models from this database, a field was left as the primary key, and a constraint unique with both fields that previously formed the composite key.

An example follows:

models.py

```py
class Preciosventalista(models.Model):
    idlistaprecio = models.OneToOneField(Listasprecios, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idlistaprecio', primary_key=True)
    idarticu = models.ForeignKey(Articulos, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idarticu')
    porcendescue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    cohefi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    precioneto = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    precioventa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'preciosventalista'
        unique_together = (('idlistaprecio', 'idarticu'),)
```

serializers.py

```py
class ArticulosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Articulos
        fields='__all__'        

class PreciosVentaListaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articulo = ArticulosSerializer(source='idarticu', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Preciosventalista
        fields='__all__'
```

apiviews.py

```py
class PreciosVentaListaList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Preciosventalista.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PreciosVentaListaSerializer

class PreciosVentaListaDetalle(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Preciosventalista.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PreciosVentaListaSerializer
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('v1/preciosventalista/', PreciosVentaListaList.as_view(), name='preciosventalista_list'),
    path('v1/preciosventalista/<int:pk>', PreciosVentaListaDetalle.as_view(), name='preciosventalista_detalle')
]
```

The error when calling the service ( /api/v1/preciosventalista/1 ) from postman is:

MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/v1/preciosventalista/1
get() returned more than one Preciosventalista -- it returned 75!

I couldn´t get my service to return a set of instances or to be able to filter through both fields (idlistaprice, idarticu) to return a single instance. I have tried the following without results:

apiviews.py

```py
class PreciosVentaListaDetalle(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Preciosventalista.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PreciosVentaListaSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many = true)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I am making beginner mistakes I apologize but I have been working with the framework for a short time, I would appreciate any help or guidance that can help me solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not support compound keys. You can tell it one of the fields is a primary key, but that is not the reality in the database (there are 75 records with the same value for that field, so it's not a key).

So a URL of the form `v1/preciosventalista/<int:pk>` will never work, regardless of what backend framework you use -- one integer is simply not enough information to specify which record you want.

You could have URLs of the form `v1/preciosventalista/<int:idlistaprecio>/<int:idarticu>` so you know both numbers; but you cannot use the builtin Rest Framework generic view classes as, again, Django does not support primary keys. You'll have to make your own view classes.

Comment: Finally I pass both fields in my url and do the filter in the view. Thank you very much for your suggestion was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, implement the view as follows:

apiviews.py

```py
class PreciosVentaListaList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Preciosventalista.objects.filter(idarticu=self.kwargs["pk"], idlistaprecio=self.kwargs["id"])
        return queryset
    serializer_class = PreciosVentaListaSerializer
```